# como verificar o tempo de um select no mysql com php

Tags: php, mysql

Bom eu faço um select, insert no mysql com php dessa forma:

```
$consulta = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT 
        id, 
        nome
    FROM
       produtos
");

 // Verifica erro
 if (!$consulta) { echo "ocorreu um erro";}
```

Como posso verificar se o select demorou mais de 3 segundos para carregar?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que fique mais ou menos igual a isto:

```
$timeInicial = time();

$consulta = $mysqli->query("
SELECT 
    id, 
    nome
FROM
   produtos
");

$timeFinal = time();

$intervalo = $timeInicial->diff($timeFinal);
echo $intervalo->format("%i:%s");
```

Não testei, não vai te retornar o tempo exato da execução do sql, mas o tempo total do envio da requisição até o retorno.

Comment: Bom tentei da sua forma, e fica dando esse erro 'Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on integer in'

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `max_statement_time` para impedir que a query demore mais do que 3 segundos para ser executada, por exemplo:

**MariaDB 10.1:**

```
SET STATEMENT MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 3000 FOR SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE vaiDemorar = 1
```

**MySQL 5.7.7+:** <sub>(via [`Optimize Hint`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html))</sub>

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(3000) */ * FROM tabela WHERE vaiDemorar = 1
```

*Todos os casos:*

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 3000;
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE vaiDemorar = 1;
```

> *Isso afeta todos os SELECT que fizer na mesma sessão.*

Isso irá interromper a execução da query caindo em "ocorreu um erro" caso demore mais do que 3 segundos para ser completada.

---

Se o seu intuito é apenas identifica possíveis lentidões e querys lentas pode definir um [`slow_query_log_file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file) e então habilitar o [`slow_query_log`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log), assim poderá descobrir os problemas nas queries.

---

Se realmente deseja descobrir o tempo de execução da query no PHP, então utilize o `profiling`, da seguinte maneira:

```
// Habilite o profiling
$mysqli->query('SET PROFILING = 1');

// Sua query, neste caso um exemplo de 2 + 2:
$matematica = $mysqli->query('SELECT 2 + 2');

list($resultado) = $matematica->fetch_row();

// Obtêm duração da query:
$profiling = $mysqli->query('SHOW profiles');

list(,$tempo_execução) = $profiling->fetch_row();

// Mostra o resultado:    
echo $tempo_execução;
echo '<br>';
echo $resultado;
```

Resultado:

```
0.00009929
4
```

Logo, bastaria utilizar:

```
if($tempo_execução > 3){
   echo 'Demorou mais de três segundos';
}
```